# Synchronized getinstance method from SQLiteOpenHelper class can't be called (can't resolved) from repository class

Tags: android, sqlite, instances

I want to Use a `Singleton` to instantiate the `SQLiteOpenHelper` like [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html).

I have tried put this code in my SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```java
public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}
```

But when I try to call that method from my repository class like this:

```java
public UserAccountRepository(Context context) {
    super(context);
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
}
```

android studio shows the error:

> cannot resolve symbol getinstance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` is used to create a new object and to call it constructor.

This is not what you actually want to do (that's already done by `getInstance`); you just want to assign the return value of `getInstace` to some local variable.
Just drop that `new`.